# How to avoid clang-format from formatting the curly brackets?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang-format

Usually, I'd like to attach the curly bracket with the previous line, but I want a line break before it sometimes. for example, while using constructor initializers:

```
constexpr vector(vector&& other)
    : alloc_ { ::std::move(other.alloc_) },
      data_begin_ { other.data_begin_ },
      data_end_ { other.data_end_ },
      storage_end_ { other.storage_end_ } {
    other.data_begin_ = other.data_end_ = other.storage_end_ = {};
}
```

It's a bit ugly. while adding a line break might be better.

```
constexpr vector(vector&& other)
    : alloc_ { ::std::move(other.alloc_) },
      data_begin_ { other.data_begin_ },
      data_end_ { other.data_end_ },
      storage_end_ { other.storage_end_ } 
{
    other.data_begin_ = other.data_end_ = other.storage_end_ = {};
}
```

However, clangd has no such details settings. Of course It's possible to disable clang-format by a comment `//clang-format off`, but it will disable other options in the mean time, so I'd like to set the clang-format style options to prevent clangd from formatting the curly bracket. Yet I met some problems.

I had searched the website https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html to edit the `.clang-format` file, but I didn't find specialized options to disable the formatting curly brackets, and the option `BreakBeforeBraces` cannot have value like `leave` as well. So I tried commenting off the option `BreakBeforeBraces`, but the clang-tidy still formatted the curly bracket by value  `attach`, which might be the default setting. So how can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom` (with `BraceWrapping.*`) doesn't give you sufficient control?

Comment: @Jeremy I want a value like "Leave"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option if needed for a specific point in the code (as opposed to *everywhere*) is empty comments:

```
constexpr vector(vector&& other)
    : alloc_ { ::std::move(other.alloc_) },
      data_begin_ { other.data_begin_ },
      data_end_ { other.data_end_ },
      storage_end_ { other.storage_end_ } //
{
    other.data_begin_ = other.data_end_ = other.storage_end_ = {};
}
```

By adding an extra `//` at the end of a line, you force clang-format to preserve the line-break.

Answer (score 1):

Clang format has quite a few detailed options.
Maybe these settings will work for you :

```
    ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
    PackConstructorInitializers: Never
    BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
    BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
    SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
```

I usually look here for my options : https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: emmm, thanks for your answer. But actually I have mentioned this website in my question, and these options may not solve my problem

Comment: Ok I meant I look there too. And yes finding the "right" combination can be tricky